# print statement that generates pandas runtime warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, warnings

How do I print the statement that generates the RuntimeWarning? All I get when my code executes is

/opt/local/lib/python2.7/numpy-1.10.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3142: RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in median
  RuntimeWarning)

I don't know which line in my code throws up this warning. Short of going through every median function call is there a way to print the line number?

Answer (score 0):

Run your code with the option `-W error` to convert the warning to an error.  The traceback will show where the error occurred.

E.g.

```
python -W error code.py
```

To convert just `RuntimeWarning`s to errors, use

```
python -W error::RuntimeWarning error code.py
```

You can also filter on the message in the warning. E.g.

```
python -W error:Invalid code.py
```

For more information about the `-W` option, see https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W

Comment: Can the "warning to error" be enforced only on RuntimeWarning? I want to ignore a bunch of DeprecationWarnings.